# Why are characters flashing during conversations?

Tags: mass-effect-3, technical-issues

During the conversation with the Illusive Man at his base, Shepard's character model keeps flashing. What is causing this, and is it possible to fix?

I am playing on the PC with all graphics on max. My GPU is a Radeon HD 6870.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well upon some more research, it seems that this is just part of the game, and no fault on my end.

Hopefully it gets fixed in a future patch.

Answer (score 0):

This might just be a case of needing to upgrade your graphics card drivers.

[AMD Graphics Card Drivers](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx)

[nVidia Graphics Card Drivers](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us)

Edit: Just for clarification, this usually happens when the subtle movement of a model, in this case Shepard, is having its lighting updated inappropriately. This could be a restriction on older graphics chipsets too.

Comment: I just updated them an hour ago.

Comment: As per my recent edit, I am using a current chip.

Comment: Strange I have the same chip.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried playing around with the video settings? I'm actually using the same card, bought it specifically for ME3 and Skyrim. I was having this issue as well while talking to garrus and liara, but I fixed it by lowering the graphical settings, playing for a bit, restarting the game, and then raising them again. I am unsure whether this will work for you or not, but it can't hurt.